# Python Solution to Leet Code Problem is Failing when Submitted but works on custom input?

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, dynamic-programming

My Solution is failing at one test case each time I'm trying to submit, but when I'm giving the same input for which it is failing as custom input it is working as expected.

Can someone help me with this?

Please check this screenshot.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgbKK.png)
This is Question Number 121 from LeetCode.

Code:

```py
class Solution:
    dp = []
    maxSP = 0
    def calcProf(self, prices, i, n):
        #dp[n-1] = 0 is the base case.
        if i < 0:
            return
        dp = Solution.dp
        
        Solution.maxSP = max(Solution.maxSP, prices[i+1])
        prof = Solution.maxSP - prices[i]
        dp[i] = max(prof, dp[i+1])
        
        self.calcProf(prices, i-1, n)

    def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
        n = len(prices)
        if n == 1:
            return 0
        Solution.dp = [0] * (n)
        
        self.calcProf(prices, n-2, n)
        print("MaxSP: ", Solution.maxSP)
        print("dp: ", Solution.dp)
        return Solution.dp[0]
```

Comment: You need to explain what it's supposed to do.

Comment: calc_prof instead of calcProf

Comment: also, max_sp instead of maxSP

Comment: @rv.kvetch how does that change anything? It is working for custom input the same test-case.

Comment: sorry it's just bother me when i'm reading through the code. it's a minor thing but matters to me for some reason.

Comment: @Barmar This is Leet-Code Question Number 121, This is my solution attempt at it, logically seems fine but when submitted it fails at one case and when given same case as custom input it works fine as expected.

Comment: @rv.kvetch that's alright. Please try to copy/paste the code to Leet-Code question 121 and modify the casing and see if it works out for you.

Comment: just do `self.dp = []` and `self.maxSP=0` in `maxprofit` function. Btw do you know how `Solution.dp` or `self.dp` work differently. your solution is right, but you need to make these changes

Comment: @sahasrara62 I'm assuming Solution.dp is class variable while self.dp becomes instance variable. Each time maxProfit is called it is called with a new list, but when the function is called, I'm setting the class variable dp to point to a new list of 0's, so please let me know what's the issue? Should I make Solution.maxSP = 0 below Solution.dp line in my code?

Comment: Thanks for the lead @sahasrara62 I managed to fix my problem now.

Comment: @Star in class variable a single data is shared between all the instance of the class. so in your case this data is continously changing and since leetcode has implementation of the running code in different way, that data / class variable data might get share with it. so this might lead to some random result sometime. so considering leetcode run 3.7+ python, i suggest you to change the `Solution` calling to `self` and it will work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using static attributes, which you should make sure to reset on every run of `maxProfit`.

Things go wrong because you don't reset `Solution.maxSP` to zero, and so `max(Solution.maxSP, prices[i+1])` is using a value that was the result of a previous run of `maxProfit`

So make sure to reset `Solution.maxSP` to zero.

Comment: I tried adding Solution.dp = [] right above the code which sets Solution.dp = [0] * n. inside the `maxProfit` function, but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Missed that, but `maxSP` was *not* reset. See updated answer.

Comment: yeah thank you so much trincot and @sahasra62 for helping me out.